# Send form data by AJAX with additional info

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a details page which contains 3 forms. My question is about "custemail" form. Thats one of them.

```
<form id="custemail" action="mail/out.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="asda" />
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="asdb" />
    <input type="hidden" name="c" value="asdc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="d" value="asdd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="e" value="asde" />
    <input type="hidden" name="f" value="asdf" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create & Send">
</form>
```

This form can not be seen by users. They just see a submit button like "Create Label & Send To Customer" .
But they need to input Customer's eMail Address. So i have a code and the submit button trigger it. And it asks the email address.
The JS code:

```
$('#sending').click(function(){
            $.prompt("What is customer's email?","",
            function(value){        

                $.ajax({
                url: "mail/out.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#custemail').serialize(),
                } ).done (function(data) {
                    $.msg("Message sent to the '"+value+"'?");
              });

            },
            function(){
                $.msg("You clicked cancel!");
            });
        });
```

So my problem is;
When the user submit the button and input the customer's email and hit the ok, Ajax must send the values from the form & email address to the "mail/out.php". and I need to know the form input names. Because I use `$_post['a']`, `$_post['b']`.... and so on

So how can I send form data with mail address?

Comment: Why not just add appropriate non-hidden input into the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add it to data, after serializing the form data:

```
data: $('#custemail').serialize() + '&email=' + value,
```

After that you will have `$_POST['email']` in PHP.

(in `value` you have the email address from the prompt's callback)

Comment: `serialize()` just does the same with you form values: `a=asda&b=asdb` etc.. So you can just extend it manually afterwards.